# Dinner at the Folkestone and Calais Eurotunnel terminals

Tags: france, food-and-drink, eurotunnel

Soon I will be making a return trip through the Eurotunnel by car, each way arriving at the terminal at about dinner time. What options are there to eat dinner there, at both the Folkestone and Calais terminals?

Comment: Are you restricting this to service physically inside the terminal, like the Burger King and Starbucks? Or in the vicinity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At Folkestone there is a building with a Burger King and Starbucks at the waiting area between ticketing and passport control. After you pick up your ticket, stay to the left to go to this area. If you've already gone to immigration, there is nothing to do but wait for your train and eat in France.

At Calais you will find the same, Burger King and Starbucks, this time after both ticketing and passport control. At the roundabout immediately after UK customs take the first exit, to the car waiting area.

If Burger King isn't doing it for you, there are much better dining options landside at the [Centre commercial Cité Europe](http://www.citeeurope.com/) in Calais, which is adjacent to the terminal. There used to be an entry directly ahead of the Eurotunnel ticket booths, but this appears to be closed. For the moment if you want to go here, try using exit 41 from the motorway.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you understand "dinner" as "grab a bite", I would suggest to have dinner somewhere in the vincinity (maybe even after having gone through the tunnel). It will be better in any case, and prices will be better as well.

Comment: Understood. If I have no time, however, I may just want to grab a bite, as you say - can this be done while waiting to board?

Comment: May be it was just my driver, but we never had to wait more than 1 minute to drive the car into the train, and the car was moving during that time. Once inside the train, we had to wait until it departed, and you can not leave the train, but you can always bring in food with you, or just walk to one of the buffet cars. Calais has a large shopping center next to the train terminal if I recall correctly. That shopping center has a self-service restaurant. Self-service restaurants in France are cheap and have reasonably good food. You may want to stop there before you queue up for the train.

Comment: And I'm afraid I don't know much about Folkestone. Usually for whatever reason, we'd take the car on the ferry out from Dover, and only take the car through the Chunnel on the train for the way back.